# Prove: if unit sphere is in open set $U$ then $\exists \epsilon>0$ s.t. $\{x\in\mathbb{R^n} | 1-\epsilon \leq d(x,0)\leq 1+\epsilon\} \subset U$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Prove: if the unit sphere $S:=\{x \in \mathbb{R^n} | d(x,0)=1\}$ is in an open set $U \subset \mathbb{R^n}$ (where $\mathbb{R^n}$ is equipped with the Euclidean metric), then $\exists \epsilon>0$ s.t. $C_{\epsilon}:=\{x\in\mathbb{R^n} | 1-\epsilon \leq d(x,0)\leq 1+\epsilon\} \subset U$.

I have tried to solve this using compactness as follows:

$U$, which by definition is a union of open balls: $U = \cup_{\alpha \in I}B(x_\alpha, \epsilon_\alpha)$ is an open cover of $S$. Since $S$ is compact (closed and bounded in $\mathbb{R^n}$) this open cover has a Lesebgue number $\delta >0$. This means that for each $s \in S$, there is some ball $B(x_\alpha, \epsilon_\alpha) \in U$ such that $B(s,\delta) \subset B(x_\alpha, \epsilon_\alpha)$.

My intuition is try and show that setting $\epsilon = \delta$ yields the desired result (at least visually it seems that this could work), but **I'm have trouble doing this formally and would appreciated knowing how to do this properly (assuming my approach is indeed correct):**

Let $x \in C_\delta$. We can choose $s \in S$ such that $d(x,s) = \min_{s \in S} d(x,s)$.  Then since:

$$d(s,0)-\delta \leq d(x,0) \leq d(s,0)+\delta $$

we obtain:

$$|d(x,0)-d(s,0)|\leq \delta$$

and due to the way we chose $s$ we obtain that [**this doesn't feel properly justified**]:

$$d(x,s)=|d(x,0)-d(s,0)|$$

and therefore that:
$$d(x,s)\leq \delta$$

meaning $x \in B(s,\delta)$.

Since $x$ was arbitrary, we obtain that for every $x \in C_\delta$ there is an $s \in S$ such that $x \in B(s,\delta)$ and therefore $x \in U$.

Any advice would be much appreciated. Also - if there are other approaches, would be great to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how nit-picky you want to be with the definition of [Lebesgue number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_number_lemma).

Let's go with wikipedia's definition so we're all on the same page.

> In topology, Lebesgue's number lemma, named after Henri Lebesgue, is a
> useful tool in the study of compact metric spaces. It states:
>
> If the metric space $\ (X,d)\ $ is compact and an open cover of $\ X\ $
> is given, then there exists a number $\ \delta >0\ $ such that every
> subset of $\ X\ $ having diameter less than $\ \delta\ $ is contained
> in some member of the cover. Such a number $ \delta\ $ is called a
> Lebesgue number of this cover.

Now you say:

> This means that for each $s \in S$, there is some ball $B(x_\alpha, \epsilon_\alpha) \in U$ such that $B(s,\delta) \subset B(x_\alpha, \epsilon_\alpha)$.

The $\ \leq\ $ sign in the definition of $\ C_{\varepsilon}\ $ is annoying here, and we must be more precise.

You should have said:

This means that for each $s \in S$, there is some *open* ball  $B(x_\alpha, \epsilon_\alpha) \in U$ such that $B(s,\delta) \subset B(x_\alpha, \epsilon_\alpha)\quad (1)$.

If these were closed balls, then $\ C_{\delta}\ $ would do, but because these are open balls, it is not necessarily the case that $\ C_{\delta}\ \subset B(s,\delta).\ $ However, clearly $\ \large{ C_{\frac{1}{2}\delta}\ } $ $ \subset B(s,\delta).$

Now let us continue on from $\ (1).$

Suppose $\ x\in\mathbb{R}^n\ $ is such that $\ 1 - \frac{\delta}{2}\ \leq\ d(x,0)\ \leq 1 + \frac{\delta}{2}.\quad $ Our aim then is to show that $\ \exists s\in S\ $ s.t. $\ x\in B(s,\delta),\ $ i.e. $\ d(x,s)< \delta.\ $ For then we could write

$$ C_{\frac{\delta}{2}} \subset \bigcup\limits_{s\in S} B(s,\delta) \subset \bigcup\limits_{\alpha \in I} B(x_{\alpha},\varepsilon_{\alpha}) = U, $$

and we would be done with the proof.

To this end, suppose $\ x\in\mathbb{R}^n\ $ is such that $\ 1 - \frac{\delta}{2}\ \leq\ \gamma = d(x,0)\ \leq 1 + \frac{\delta}{2}.\quad $ Write

$x = (x_1,\ldots,x_n)\ $ as the coordinates of $\ x\ $ in $\ \mathbb{R}^n.\ $ We have

$$ 1 - \frac{\delta}{2} \leq \sqrt{{x_1}^2 + \ldots + {x_n}^2} \leq 1 + \frac{\delta}{2}.\quad (2) $$

Define $$ s = \left(\frac{1}{\gamma} x_1,\ \frac{1}{\gamma} x_2,\ \ldots,\ \frac{1}{\gamma} x_n \right). $$

$d(s,0)=1,\ $ so $\ s\in S.$ Also, a quick calculation shows that $\ d(x,s) = \vert 1-\gamma \vert \overset{(2)}{\leq} \frac{\delta}{2} < \delta,\ $ and so $\ x\in B(s,\delta),\ $ as desired.
$$$$
Edit: "quick calculation part":

Recall: I use $\ \gamma = d(x,0)\ $ for slight brevity where necessary.

$\ d(x,s) = d\left(\ (x_1,\ldots,x_n),\ \left(\frac{1}{\gamma} x_1,\ \frac{1}{\gamma} x_2,\ \ldots,\ \frac{1}{\gamma} x_n \right) \right)$

$$ = \sqrt{ \left(x_1 - \frac{1}{\gamma} x_1\right)^2  \ldots + \left(x_n - \frac{1}{\gamma} x_n\right)^2 } = \sqrt{ \left( 1 - \frac{1}{\gamma}\right)^2 \left( {x_1}^2 + \ldots + {x_n}^2 \right) } $$

$$ = \left\vert1 - \frac{1}{\gamma}\right\vert \gamma = \left\vert \frac{\gamma - 1}{\gamma}\right\vert \gamma \overset{\gamma>0}{=} \frac{\left\vert\gamma - 1\right\vert}{\gamma}\ \gamma = \left\vert \gamma - 1 \right\vert$$

$
=
\begin{cases}
 \gamma - 1&\text{if}\,\ \gamma > 1\\
 1 - \gamma &\text{if}\,\ \gamma \leq 1\\
\end{cases}
$

$
=
\begin{cases}
 d(x,0) - 1&\text{if}\,\ d(x,0) > 1\\
 1 - d(x,0) &\text{if}\,\ d(x,0) \leq 1\\
\end{cases}
$

Either way, the above together with $\ (2)\ $ implies $\ d(x,s) \leq \frac{\delta}{2} < \delta.$

Comment: Are you able to provide the "quick calculation shows that.." part? It's similar to what I wasn't able to justify. I understand that this is the distance between $x$ and its unit-length vector $\frac{x}{||x||_2}$ and so this should be correct, but I must be missing something simple to show this formally.

Comment: @Anon - I've updated my answer to include the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

We denote $S:=\{x\in\Bbb R^n|d(x,0)=1\}$ the unit sphere and $C:=C(0;1-r;1+r)=\{x\in \Bbb R^n|1-r\leq d(x,0)\leq 1+r\}$ the cylinder with centre $0$ and radii $1-r, 1+r$. We want to show that $C\subseteq U$.

Firstly, $S\cap\partial U=\varnothing$. If this wasn' t true, there would exist a $y\in S\cap\partial U$; then, provided that $S\subseteq U$, we would obtain that $y\in U$ and $y\in \partial U$, which is false, because $U$ is open, so it contains none of its boundary. Consequently,  $S\cap\partial U=\varnothing$ is true, so $dist(S,\partial U):=δ>0$, which means that $S\subseteq D(0;1+δ)=\{x\in \Bbb R^n|\ ||x||\leq 1+δ\}\subseteq U$. By choosing $\epsilon:=\frac {δ}{2}>0$ we finally obtain that $D(0;1-\epsilon)\subseteq S\subseteq D(0;1+\epsilon)\subseteq D(0;1+δ)\subseteq U$, so $C\subseteq U$, because $D(0;1+\epsilon)\supseteq C=D(0;1+\epsilon)\setminus (D(0;1-\epsilon))^\circ$. q.e.d.